# Absolute positioning and floats

Tags: javascript, css

I have a rather unusual layout that I'm trying to make a reality. There is a div containing, for sake of argument, that needs to be fixed at 200px from the left and from the top of a wrapper.

I then have a collection of square images that would all be floated and would continue to the edge of the browser window, and wrap around the absolutely positioned div. I know that absolute positioning takes the div out of the doc flow, which means I can't think of a simple solution for this.

Has anyone worked out a way around this kind of problem? Potentially with javascript?

EDIT: Here's the rough layout: [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/809/layouton.png/)

Comment: Do you have an image of what you want? Perhaps you don't need absolute positioning.

Comment: Hey, I think you're right, it needs some visuals. I've put a rough layout of the idea. The wrap is the width of the window. The red squares are images floated, in order, and the 'absolute' div is the black area. Thanks. [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/809/layouton.png/)

Comment: Do the images need to wrap around or could they go behind the black area? If so, this could simply be achieved using a background image.

Comment: Ideally all images would wrap around, and be in order. I've built an admin section where the client can order the images as they please. But if the window size was large enough, there could be any number of images wide, heading off to the right. That is why I need a slightly unique solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want more flexibility, but just in case, if your design is reasonably fixed, you can just use 3 columns (container divs) and sort it all out per column.

If your html is fixed, you could use javascript but I don't know of any ready-made solutions.

I would probably use javascript to do some math and inject dummy images / elements behind the black box at the right positions (keeping the black box absolutely positioned). You could also do that server-side.

Comment: Hey Jeroen, I like the idea of injecting dummy images depending on window size. I'm going to have a go at that. Thanks, sounds like a good plan!

Comment: FYI, this is how I ended up accomplishing the layout & design: http://sarahgreavesart.com/ Thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Judging from your image, I would personally use a table. However, it can be achieved with floats:

(image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAqxZ.png)

```
<style>
#cont {
  width: 100px;
}   
.small {
  float:left;
  height:25px;
  width:25px;
  background-color:#00F;
}   
.big {
  float:left;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:#F00;
}   
.long {
  float:left;
  height:50px;
  width:25px;
  background-color:#F0F;
}   
.long .small {
  background-color:#F0F;
}   
</style>

<div id="cont">
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="long">
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="big"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="small"></div>
</div>
```

---

Original text:

I would do something like this:

```
<div class="absolute-wrapper">
  <div><!-- whatever content you intended for the absolute div... --></div>
  <div class="float-left">...</div>
  <div class="float-left">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

However, I feel inclined to recommend you search for another solution than an absolutely positioned element. They easily grow unmaintainable.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My problem lies in that I need the images to remain in order regardless of how many of them stretch off to the right. The order flows from left to right, and 'skips out' the areas with absolution positioning. This is my dream :)

Comment: Then you must calculate their sizes somewhere and group them as in my example. A few lines of javascript should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a canvas element, but it has downsides. You will be depending on javascript, as you will need to do all positioning in javascript.

Not to be unhelpful, but I also think you should consider how important this exact design is, simply because I don't think there is any straightforward solution, since HTML as it is today isn't really built for these kinds of layout. The future is promising though, giving us things like multi-column and flexbox...

Comment: You're right, it's not very HTML friendly. That was kind of the point though, I thought I'd try and stretch myself a bit. I have a more sensible layout as a back up, just really liked the idea of achieving something like this if possible.

Comment: Great! That's the right way to go about it :) If you manage to make it work, it'd be great to see the result!

Comment: Hey Adrian, this is what I ended up doing. http://sarahgreavesart.com Rather than being completely fluid, there are basically 3 'options', 1400 wide, 1200 wide and 1000 wide. Dummy boxes fill in behind the absolute divs.

Comment: Ah, that's really nice! Congrats on a great looking site!

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript/jQuery, it could be accomplished using the logic of the following pseudo code:

Create a function which preforms these steps....

Step 1: Remove any divs from the dom that have a class named `fakeSquare`. Something like

```
 $('.fakeSquare').remove();
```

Step 2: Calculate the number of red divs in one row. Store this number in `squaresPreRow`. Something like: `var squaresPreRow = floor( window width / square width )`.

Step 3: After the `squaresPreRow + 1` red square div, add two empty divs. Like so...

```
$("div.redSquare")
    .index(squaresPreRow + 1)
    .append("<div class="fakeSquare redSquare"></div><div class="fakeSquare redSquare"></div>");
```

Step 4: Add another two square for the third row...

```
$("div.redSquare")
    .index((squaresPreRow * 2) + 1)
    .append("<div class="fakeSquare redSquare"></div><div class="fakeSquare redSquare"></div>");
```

Step 5: And again...

```
$("div.redSquare")
    .index((squaresPreRow * 3) + 1)
    .append("<div class="fakeSquare redSquare"></div><div class="fakeSquare redSquare"></div>");
```

Finally you want to call this function when the DOM is ready and whenever the window changed.

This may need some tweaking, but hopefully it can get you started.